# How to improve speed of send mail?

Tags: c#, .net, email, smtp

I used Smtp Client for send mail in my application,speed of send mail is very slowly.
My code is :

```
var smtp = _settingsService.GetSettings().SMTP;
var smtpUsername = _settingsService.GetSettings().SMTPUsername;
var smtpPassword = _settingsService.GetSettings().SMTPPassword;
var smtpPort = _settingsService.GetSettings().SMTPPort;
var smtpEnableSsl = _settingsService.GetSettings().SMTPEnableSSL;

if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(smtp))
{
    return;
}
else
{
    var mySmtpClient = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient(smtp);
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(smtpUsername) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(smtpPassword))
    {
        mySmtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(smtpUsername, smtpPassword);
    }

    if (smtpEnableSsl != null)
    {
        mySmtpClient.EnableSsl = (bool)smtpEnableSsl;
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(smtpPort))
    {
        mySmtpClient.Port = Convert.ToInt32(smtpPort);
    }


        if (defaultEmail != null)
        {
            var msg = new MailMessage
            {
                IsBodyHtml = true,
                Body = defaultEmail.Body,
                From = new MailAddress(defaultEmail.EmailFrom),
                Subject = defaultEmail.Subject
            };
            msg.To.Add(defaultEmail.EmailTo);
            mySmtpClient.Send(msg);
}
```

I want to know, what is best method for highest speed send mail or how to improve speed of send mail ?

Comment: Add more ram to the mail server

Comment: I've seen a very large speed difference between the smtp server of my web provider (discountasp) and hotmail (smtp.live.com). It seems that hotmail adds +- 10 seconds delay when sending an email via smtp, just to prevent using it for spamming. Remember that hotmail doesn't do a lot of verifications when an hotmail account is created (no phone number requested for example), so many spammers are using it for that purpose while staying anonymous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is pretty basic code, it could be slow only because of I/O (network, the smtp server itself). The only thing you can do is to use asynchrony and/or parallelism if it is appropriate in your application

Comment: I know that it is slow only because setting of mail server,but i have only Gmail that it is slow because using SSL protocol,now i want you suggest another mail server for improve my speed

Comment: If the problem is in the mail server itself, it is not the proper Q/A site to ask. Try to ask at http://superuser.com/ or http://serverfault.com/